# Parse Blackbox model into an Optimization Algorithm

Tags: python, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I have a function:
 = f(_1,_2, _3, _4 … _,)

Where f() is a blackbox model, how do I parse it into an optimize algorithm like GA for constrained minimisation or maximisation of y?

this is what my code looks like:

```
#Importing libraries
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.25,shuffle=True, random_state=0)

model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=200,min_samples_split=2,min_samples_leaf=2, max_depth=20)
results = model.fit (x_train, y_train)
y_pred = results.predict(_1,_2, _3, _4 … _)
```

My objective is to set some constraints on the input variables (_1,_2, _3, _4 … _,) to minimize the predicted y (y_pred) using an optimization algorithm like GA.

Comment: This is far too broad of a question to get a concrete answer.

Comment: Well we need more details. Can the function be called? Is it wrapped in such a manner that the optimiser can evaluate solutions? What is the initial setup? What is the expected output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AirSquid I have added some detail, please review.

Comment: @jlandercy I have added some detail, please review